# Looking for a AutoZoom browser plugin

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, plugins

I have a pretty large 24" wide screen with a pretty high resolution.  When I browse, some sites have a fixed layout and there is basically a narrow column.  So I typically zoom in to the point just before the level where I have to scroll horizontally.

Is there a browser plugin that auto-zooms in (or via a button or gesture or whatever) to the max available real estate?  I'd prefer a plugin for Chrome, but Firefox will do too.

Comment: you'll LOVE Opera :)

Comment: @Molly I've give Opera a chance probably like 10 times over the years.  But the UI is simply not for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're looking for firefox answers, they are here:
[Make Firefox automatically set zoom level for new webpages](https://superuser.com/questions/89393/make-firefox-automatically-zoom-webpages)