# How can I increase the default zoom-in for Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, zoom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Firefox automatically set zoom level for new webpages](https://superuser.com/questions/89393/make-firefox-automatically-set-zoom-level-for-new-webpages)

Windows 7, Firefox 7.0.1

I want to increase the size of everything on the screen without changing the display resolution. For all other Windows items, I increase the size in `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display`. But for Firefox, how can I increase the display size within Firefox?

More specifically, I want to have the zoom-in level as one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. It seems that such a zoom-in can be set to each website. How can I make one zoom-in level as default for all websites?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Firefox addon *[Default FullZoom Level](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/default-fullzoom-level/)*.

Comment: The link to the "Default FullZoom Level" addon is broken.