# How to permanently zoom in Firefox without using addons?

Tags: firefox, user-interface

How can you permanently zoom in Firefox without using an add-on?

Does Firefox have a zoom option similar to Internet Explorer, Chrome & Opera's **zoom to x%** option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Notice:** These settings may not work with version 29 or newer.

Open Firefox and type `about:config` into the address bar and search for "zoom".

In the search results, change two settings as below.

```
browser.zoom.siteSpecific false
zoom.minPercent 150
```

The value of `zoom.minPercent` must be an integer.

Comment: Emperically determined: Firefox must be *restarted* before it takes effect, at least for zoom.minPercent. Tested with Firefox 8.0.1 (Portable edition)

Comment: This does not work with Firefox 29

Comment: I guess this is a bug in 29. I did the changes and restart the firefox. All sites started in %100. When I touch ctrl+scroll, page became %150 zoomed. I think, somehow, they broke zoom.minPercent behaviour option on startup.

Comment: Version 47 and still this method doesn't work

Comment: Or one can simple set zoom.minPercent 150 and zoom.minPercent 150.

Comment: @mk1024 I think you said same thing twice.

Answer (score 3):

From https://superuser.com/a/1268867 :

> The default zoom in Firefox can be reset to any value for all webpages without installing an extension.
>
> 1. In the Firefox address bar type: `about:config`
> 2. Search for this preference: `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`
> 3. Replace the default value of `-1.0` with the new percentage zoom. For example, if you want to change the default zoom from the default value of 100% to 125%, then change the value of `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` to `1.25`

This affects the GUI and web content, not just the web content or just the text.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you ask for, but you can increase the minimum font size on you browser. That way you'll have larger letters.

like this: 
[increase-min-fint-size](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-zoom#w_how-do-i-set-the-minimum-text-size-for-text-zoom)

Comment: not just the font size .... the whole webpage

Comment: scroll up the page - you might find your answer.

Comment: that isn't permanent zoom

Comment: I made a little search - there seems not to be such an option. But wikipedia's acticle about firefox says, that it should remember your zooming settings for each site.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>MouseWheel</kbd> zooms, and the zoom-level is remembered on a per-site basis, unless you clear your history.

Comment: (ctrl and + ) (ctrl and -)  browser/tab wide zoom = same like ctrl mouse wheel up/down