# How to change the zoom increment in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, zoom

How do I change the zoom increment that is used by Firefox whenever I zoom-in or zoom-out of webpages?

I find that the default zoom increment is a bit too big for my taste.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this as follows (I tried it with Firefox 10.0.2 here):

- Type `about:config` in the address bar
- Filter for `toolkit.zoomManager.zoomValues`

This will show you the various zoom "steps" the browser has. The steps are specified as decimal numbers (representing precentages of the original, so .3 means 30% of original), separated by a `,`. See *[Tweak Firefox 3 full page zoom](http://mozillalinks.org/2008/06/tweak-firefox-3-full-page-zoom/)* for the details.

Comment: This works, but ***Firefox must be restarted*** before it takes effect (at least in the most recent version of Firefox, 34). For instance, opening a new tab is not enough.

Comment: Restarting Firefox required: similar to Super User question *[How to permanently zoom in Firefox without using addons?](http://superuser.com/questions/374515/how-to-permanently-zoom-in-firefox-without-using-addons/374520#374520)*.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work anymore in FF 51+ what gives?

Comment: I don't have enough points to comment on Bhargav Bhat answer, but it seems that the `toolkit.zoomManager.zoomValues` as not effect when you use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Mousewheel</kbd>. But it is taken into account when you zoom: - Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>
- Using the Zoom feature in the Hamburger menu.